# Difference between "Gegenteile" und "Gegensätze"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I see the following examples from dictionary:

> - Das chemische Gegenteil von Base ist Säure.
> - Fortschritt und Naturschutz sollten kein Gegensatz sein.

I also see both usages: im Gegensatz/Gegenteil zu ...

For noun form, I assume they are interchangeable. But I am not sure if there is some minor difference in usage here. Is it possible to say:

> - Base und Säure sind chemische Gegensätze voneinander.
> - Fortschritt und Naturschutz sollten kein Gegenteil sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ein Gegensatz" is the relation between a thing and its opposite ("Gegenteil"):

> - "Gegensätze" exist between big and small, between poor and rich, between wet and dry, etc.
> - Large is the opposite ("Gegenteil") of small, poor is the opposite ("Gegenteil") of rich, wet is the opposite ("Gegenteil") of dry, etc.

I would use the top two for your example sentences. Because the "Gegenteil von Base ist Säure" and not the "Gegensatz".

**To your example sentences:**

> - Das chemische Gegenteil von Base ist Säure.

*Correct*, then the opposite from "Base" is "Säure"

> - Fortschritt und Naturschutz sollten kein Gegensatz sein.

*Correct*, then they aren‘t opposite ("Gegenteil") to each other.

> - Base und Säure sind chemische Gegensätze voneinander.

*Not correct*, then "Gegensätze" needs no "voneinander", then with "Gegensätze" you compare two things already. Otherwise it would be correct. <s>"voneinander"</s>

> - Fortschritt und Naturschutz sollten kein Gegenteil sein.

*Not correct*, it makes no sense... Then "Fortschritt" isn‘t the opposite ("Gegenteil") from "Naturschutz". The opposite from "Fortschritt" is "Rückschritt".